# A battery pin in my Canon 1300D looks bent, is it damaged?

Tags: canon, battery, equipment-damage

One of the pins in the battery slot of my new Canon 1300d appears to be bent/damaged. I'm pretty sure that I did not damage the pins by inserting the battery in the wrong way. I've also inserted and removed the battery just a couple of times which makes me wonder if this is by design or I received a damaged piece ? Nevertheless, The camera turns on and off just fine.

Please find the following picture for reference. The orange reference straight light is drawn with respect to the other two (possibly) unbent pins.

[image: bent battery pin Canon 1300D]

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Is there a problem that you're trying to solve that led you to conclude there was a problem within the battery compartment?

Comment: What about the photo above do you think is not normal?

Answer (score 1):

> The camera turns on and off just fine.

As the old adage goes... "If it ain't broke, don't fix it". Relax and enjoy your camera :)